# After deploy - Web App looking at development files

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

After deploying my web app, I am getting an exception error. After looking at the stack trace, I noticed that the web app was looking for files in my development directory, and not the IIS directory. For deployment, I am copying the files from my development directory to the IIS directory.

> C:\Users\esp\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Password Utility\passwordutility.aspx.cs

The exception being raised:

> please check your email 
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80005008): One or more input parameters are invalid --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args) at Email_User.ResetConfirmation.ModifyUser(String username) in C:\Users\esp\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Password Utility\ResetConfirmation.aspx.cs:line 385

Comment: Are you doing an actual publish?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace so we can see where this goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debug symbols will report the full path of the file when it was complied, not when the error was generated.  So even though you're seing your local path before the .cs file name, it's not actually looking in that path for the files.

Comment: +1. Beginners should pay much more attention to learn about debugging things like this.